# How to use parent selector and child selectors which share common css in less files

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

I have my less program as below, How do I use combination of parent selector and group of child selectors which share common css to achieve better modular less file. In below example I have @theGoodThings which will have all the child classes who share same css separated by ",". I am not sure how I can use @theGoodThings in the below example.Any other suggestions is welcome. I found a online compiler from less to css which I used to generate css http://lesscss.org/less-preview/

```
<!-- language: lang-css -->

    @seenByOrangeHighlight: #FFE8D2;
    @seenByOrangeLightHighlight: #FFF2E6;
    @collapsedOrangeHover: #FFDFC2;
    @theGoodThings: ~".seen-by-a, seen-by-b .seen-by-c, .seen-by-custom-color-2, .test-op";
    .highlight- {
      &seen-by-a .seen-by-a, &seen-by-b .seen-by-b, &seen-by-c .seen-by-c,
      &seen-by-custom-color-2 .seen-by-custom-color-2, &test-op .test-op {
          background-color: @seenByOrangeHighlight;
          &.non-user-resource {
              background-color: @seenByOrangeLightHighlight;
          }
      }
      &seen-by-a, &seen-by-b, &seen-by-c,
      &seen-by-custom-color-2, &test-op {
          &.collapsed-view {
              .table-row {
                  &.seen-by-a, &.seen-by-b, &.seen-by-c, &.seen-by-custom-color-2, &.test-op {
                      &:hover {
                         background-color: @collapsedOrangeHover;
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
    }

<!-- end snippet -->
```

This will output to css as below

```
<!-- language: lang-css -->

    .highlight-seen-by-a .seen-by-a,
    .highlight-seen-by-b .seen-by-b,
    .highlight-seen-by-c .seen-by-c,
    .highlight-seen-by-custom-color-2 .seen-by-custom-color-2,
    .highlight-test-op .test-op {
      background-color: #FFE8D2;
    }
    .highlight-seen-by-a .seen-by-a.non-user-resource,
    .highlight-seen-by-b .seen-by-b.non-user-resource,
    .highlight-seen-by-c .seen-by-c.non-user-resource,
    .highlight-seen-by-custom-color-2 .seen-by-custom-color-2.non-user-resource,
    .highlight-test-op .test-op.non-user-resource {
      background-color: #FFF2E6;
    }
    .highlight-seen-by-a.collapsed-view .table-row.seen-by-a:hover,
    .highlight-seen-by-b.collapsed-view .table-row.seen-by-a:hover,
    .highlight-seen-by-c.collapsed-view .table-row.seen-by-a:hover,
    .highlight-seen-by-custom-color-2.collapsed-view .table-row.seen-by-a:hover,
    .highlight-test-op.collapsed-view .table-row.seen-by-a:hover,
    .highlight-seen-by-a.collapsed-view .table-row.seen-by-b:hover,
    .highlight-seen-by-b.collapsed-view .table-row.seen-by-b:hover,
    .highlight-seen-by-c.collapsed-view .table-row.seen-by-b:hover,
    .highlight-seen-by-custom-color-2.collapsed-view .table-row.seen-by-b:hover,
    .highlight-test-op.collapsed-view .table-row.seen-by-b:hover,
    .highlight-seen-by-a.collapsed-view .table-row.seen-by-c:hover,
    .highlight-seen-by-b.collapsed-view .table-row.seen-by-c:hover,
    .highlight-seen-by-c.collapsed-view .table-row.seen-by-c:hover,
    .highlight-seen-by-custom-color-2.collapsed-view .table-row.seen-by-c:hover,
    .highlight-test-op.collapsed-view .table-row.seen-by-c:hover,
    .highlight-seen-by-a.collapsed-view .table-row.seen-by-custom-color-2:hover,
    .highlight-seen-by-b.collapsed-view .table-row.seen-by-custom-color-2:hover,
    .highlight-seen-by-c.collapsed-view .table-row.seen-by-custom-color-2:hover,
    .highlight-seen-by-custom-color-2.collapsed-view .table-row.seen-by-custom-color-2:hover,
    .highlight-test-op.collapsed-view .table-row.seen-by-custom-color-2:hover,
    .highlight-seen-by-a.collapsed-view .table-row.test-op:hover,
    .highlight-seen-by-b.collapsed-view .table-row.test-op:hover,
    .highlight-seen-by-c.collapsed-view .table-row.test-op:hover,
    .highlight-seen-by-custom-color-2.collapsed-view .table-row.test-op:hover,
    .highlight-test-op.collapsed-view .table-row.test-op:hover {
      background-color: #FFDFC2;
    }

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: This post is most likely going to be removed as being opinion based. Please change the post and ask a specific question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion scott. I have modified the question.

Comment: I'd still be more specific. "How do I use combination of parent selector and @ "?  To achieve what?  Explain what you are hoping to get.

Comment: @ScottMarcus updated the question which I believe will  be more meaningful and useful for who wants to make modular less files.

Comment: Just a suggestion - you should probably have a re-look at your HTML and the way you are using classes. That seems overly complicated. (We can suggest improvements if you show your markup).